# Asynctask class to rerun itself again?

Tags: java, android

Hello i have a class which runs my getQus class(via asynctask)
The problem right now is that im trying to set it in such a way that if 
my return result is null, to rerun the getQus again with updated variables, i.e to increase my topic& lvl till i get a valid result.

This is my flow of my system. 
1st class( set topic&lvl)-> Pass topic&lvl over to getQus -> getQus returns result via onPostExecute(delegate).

1st Class Code

```
 public void GenerateQus(){
    //run code to get new qus
    x.setLvl(lvl);
    x.setTopic(topic);
    System.out.println("GENERATEQUS:"+ lvl +" , "+topic);
    new getQus(CAT.this).execute(x);
}
```

getQus Class

```
    protected Question doInBackground(Level... params) {
    int r = params[0].getLvl();
    int z = params[0].getTopic();
    System.out.println("getQlvl:" + r);
    System.out.println("getQtopic:" + z);

    String range = String.valueOf(r);
    String topic = String.valueOf(z);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("range",range));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("topic",topic));
    int q_id = 0;
    String result=null;
    String q_qus =" ";
    String result2 = " ";

    Question q = new Question();


     InputStream is = null;
        try {
            Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
               String ip = g.getip();
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://"+ip+"/fyp/qus.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                result2=sb.toString();
                System.out.println("TEDASD: "+result2);

                if(result2.equals("[]")){
                    //to rerun again
                }
```

What should i do so that getQus will re-call itself again? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you just want to rerun logic in doInBackground. So, why don't you just do something like this?

```
protected Question doInBackground(Level... params) {
    Question q;
    while((q = doTheStuff(params))==null){
        updateParams(params);
    }
    return q;
}

private Question doTheStuff(Level.. params){
    //your logic here
}

private void updateParams(Level.. params){
    //update params here
}
```

If you can update x only in the main thread, you can reexecute the task in onPostExecute:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    private X x = new X();

    @Override protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new AsyncTask<X, String, Long>() {

            @Override protected Long doInBackground(final X... params) {
                //  do something here
                return null;
            }

            @Override protected void onPostExecute(final Long result) {
                if (result == null) {
                    //  update args and restart task
                    x.setFoo("a");
                    x.setBar("b");
                    execute(x);
                }

            }
        }.execute(x);
    }

    private class X {
        String foo;
        String bar;

        public void setFoo(final String foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        public void setBar(final String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In onPostExecute() method you will get the result. so if your result is null there the start the AysncTask there itselt.

Comment: Hi, Yeah how do i start it again? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to start again. I mean if you dont get result then your asyncTask will keep run.

Comment: Hi,  because I run this getqus class to retrieve question details based on level and topic. If let's say return null due to no result, I would like to rerun the class with auto updated variable till I get a valid response back

Comment: If lets say if null, i will set lvl++ , topic++ and run the method again. if fails, will ++ till it gets a valid result. Im trying to make getqus method pass back a proper question object back to my main class instead of empty.